# TFS on Automation Tests Suits - How to Run

Tags: tfs, automation, automated-tests

I have 2 executables, an app and an automation test app who will perform actions on the app. My automation tests are basically NUNIT tests who calls Chrome Web Driver.

Everything is hosted at TFS. In my build definition, i run sanity checks for every PR. I wanted to expand that. The automation tests are divided into many different categories (being Sanity a category). I've been seeing some stuff related to TFS Test Suits, and my idea was to make in a way whenever when someone makes a PR, he could choose some test category to run on that PR using that build. So in a easyer way of sayng, if my PR changes how 'blue buttons work' ill run the 'blue buttons test suit' on my pr.

Would using Test Suits be the best solution for this ? Has any1 done this or have any nice information on how to achieve this ?

Thanks for any responses !! Best regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be able to use the [Visual Studio Test Agent Deploy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment) and [Run Functional tests](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/run-functional-tests) steps in your build definition to run auto tests on build agents.

1. Associated test methods with test cases in Visual Studio.
2. Create a build definition to build your project and add the 2 steps I mentioned above. In the Run Functional Test step, select the test suites which contains those test cases in step1.
   [image]

More details please refer this blog: [Executing Automated tests in Build vNext using Test Plan, Test Suites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/)

Comment: I see. Would there be a way to handle choosing test suits per PR ? Instead of running the standard build definition on PR's, somehow a way to choose which tests suits you would include in your build.

Comment: @GabrielSlomka Sorry, this is not support for now. You could submit a uservocie [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS  Admin and PM will kindly review your suggestion.